# visual studio code and Parse.com autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Is it possible in any way to make Microsoft Visual Studio Code to auto complete Parse JS SDK? 
I know it is possible with some other IDEs by importing the parse-1.5.0.js file, but i found this IDE better...

Comment: The way to do this would be by finding a "TypeScript Definition file" (.tsd) for Parse, or even creating one yourself (not impossible, but possibly a lot of work). This is the case even if you want to work in pure JavaScript - Visual Studio Code can read TypeScript information and use it to grant intellisense to a file. See VSC's tutorials on setting up TypeScript in a project, and only follow the parts about setting up definitions.

Comment: i'm trying to do it with this file: [link](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/parse) and the following tutorial [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript) but it's not working.What do i miss?
thanks.

Comment: Why don't you edit your post with your current `jsconfig.json` file, and a basic explanation of your project layout?

Answer (score 1):

With [nodejs and npm-cli installed](https://nodejs.org/en/), get definition file packager manager([tsd-cli](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/)) and install `parse.d.ts`:

```
npm install -g tsd 
tsd install parse --save
```

Use `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json` to enable [autocomplete](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) without reference by comments.

VSCode will find parse.d.ts file and just works!
This process is same to any other library.

Comment: It looks like tsd is deprecated. Do you now any alternative?